# Loop for Points in 2D triangles

Tags: python, 2d, point

I have a function in Python to find if a point is in a 2d triangle, that looks like this:

```
def isInsideTriangle(P,p1,p2,p3): #is P inside triangle made by p1,p2,p3?
    x,x1,x2,x3 = P[0],p1[0],p2[0],p3[0]
    y,y1,y2,y3 = P[1],p1[1],p2[1],p3[1]
    full = abs (x1 * (y2 - y3) + x2 * (y3 - y1) + x3 * (y1 - y2))
    first = abs (x1 * (y2 - y) + x2 * (y - y1) + x * (y1 - y2))
    second = abs (x1 * (y - y3) + x * (y3 - y1) + x3 * (y1 - y))
    third = abs (x * (y2 - y3) + x2 * (y3 - y) + x3 * (y - y2))
    return abs(first + second + third - full) < .0000000001
```

My 'P' is a bunch of (about 15) points, which come from this (piece of) file:

```
PointXY
[387.9385, 200.0]
PointXY
[200.0, 387.9385]
PointXY
[200.0, 387.9385]
PointXY
[200.0, 353.2089]
PointXY
```

My p1, p2 and p3 are the corner coordinates in the triangles. They come from this (piece of) file:

```
TriangleXY
[193.0371, 0.1218346]
[193.0244, 0.1218346]
[186.0572, 0.4871899]
TriangleXY
[206.9799, 0.1218346]
[206.9756, 0.1218346]
[213.9428, 0.4871899]
TriangleXY
[193.0244, 0.1218346]
[193.0371, 0.1218346]
[200.0, 0.0]
TriangleXY
[206.9756, 0.1218346]
```

What I want my script to do, is IF any point(s) is in (or on the side of) any triangle(s), return me the (3) specific coordinates from that triangle p1, p2 and p3, and the specific point P that's in it. It now only works for a single P and a single set of p1, p2 and p3, and I would like to have it work for all the points P and all the triangle corners p1, p2 and p3. Anybody have an idea how to adjust this in my script accordingly? My P and p1, p2 and p3 are called by these scripts:

```
# triangle coordinates p1 p2 p3
g = open("spheretop1.stl", "r")
m = open("TriangleXYcoordinates.gcode", "w")
searchlines = g.readlines()
file = ""

for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if "outer loop" in line:
        p1 = map(float, searchlines[i+1].split()[1:3])
        p2 = map(float, searchlines[i+2].split()[1:3])
        p3 = map(float, searchlines[i+3].split()[1:3])
        m.write("TriangleXY" + "\n" + str(p1) + "\n" + str(p2) + "\n" + str(p3) + "\n")

# Point coordinates P
import json
h = open("PointXYcoordinates.gcode", "r")
searchlines = h.readlines()
file = ""

for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if "PointXY" in line:
        P = json.loads(searchlines[i+1].strip())
```

Comment: @idjaw is the information in this question clear enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
def pointsInsideTriangles(points,triangles):
    for (P in points):
        for (t in triangles):
            if isInsideTriangle(P,t[0],t[1],t[2]):
                print("Point " + str(P) + " is inside traingle " + str(t))
```

Altogether you'd have something like:

```
def isInsideTriangle(P,p1,p2,p3): #is P inside triangle made by p1,p2,p3?
    x,x1,x2,x3 = P[0],p1[0],p2[0],p3[0]
    y,y1,y2,y3 = P[1],p1[1],p2[1],p3[1]
    full = abs (x1 * (y2 - y3) + x2 * (y3 - y1) + x3 * (y1 - y2))
    first = abs (x1 * (y2 - y) + x2 * (y - y1) + x * (y1 - y2))
    second = abs (x1 * (y - y3) + x * (y3 - y1) + x3 * (y1 - y))
    third = abs (x * (y2 - y3) + x2 * (y3 - y) + x3 * (y - y2))
    return abs(first + second + third - full) < .0000000001

def pointsInsideTriangles(points,triangles):
    for (P in points):
        for (t in triangles):
            if isInsideTriangle(P,t[0],t[1],t[2]):
                print("Point " + str(P) + " is inside triangle " + str(t))


# triangle coordinates p1 p2 p3
points = [];
triangles = [];
g = open("spheretop1.stl", "r")
m = open("TriangleXYcoordinates.gcode", "w")
searchlines = g.readlines()
file = ""

for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if "outer loop" in line:
        p1 = map(float, searchlines[i+1].split()[1:3])
        p2 = map(float, searchlines[i+2].split()[1:3])
        p3 = map(float, searchlines[i+3].split()[1:3])
        m.write("TriangleXY" + "\n" + str(p1) + "\n" + str(p2) + "\n" + str(p3) + "\n")
        triangles.append([p1,p2,p3])


# Point coordinates P
import json
h = open("PointXYcoordinates.gcode", "r")
searchlines = h.readlines()
file = ""

for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if "PointXY" in line:
        P = json.loads(searchlines[i+1].strip())
        points.append(P)

pointsInsideTriangles(points,triangles)
```

Comment: I get an error when I try to run the code, "for (P in Points)" : invalid syntax. (after def pointsInsideTriangles(points,triangles)).]

Comment: use the same capitalisation for the `points` variable. Change the line to `for (P in points):`

Comment: Thanks, one thing left, do you know how to remove all the duplicates that my function pointsInsideTriangles(points,triangles) gives me? Basically the print at the end gives me a whole list of values, but some are duplicates..

Comment: No problem! :) This is because you have a duplicate in your points list provided. Maybe check if the P is in points before you add each one.

Comment: Can I also just adjust the print line in my def? It also gives me duplicates for some Points that arent duplicates in my points list.

Comment: Hmmm. If there are no duplicate points in the list and no duplicate triangles in the list, there should be no duplicates printed. Have you checked the list of triangles for duplicated sets?

Comment: Yes I checked, there are no duplicates in the triangleXY file nor in the pointXY file. Yet it still prints about 10 duplicates for, for instance, point [200.0, 100.0].